# How do i change the icon of a folder in windows?

Tags: windows, directory, icons

I'm trying to change the icon of a folder windows with a custom icon for my program. I know I can by right clicking folder and using properties to change the icon, but I need the icon to be permanently different for part of my software I'm making. This is a NWJS app.

EDIT of what I've done:

`desktop.ini`

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
ConfirmFileOp=0
NoSharing=0
IconFile=Folder.ico
IconIndex=1
InfoTip=Secure Drive
```

**Path: "D:\SECURE DRIVE"**

I used `attrib +s "SECURE DRIVE"` after using `CD'ing to D:\`. I've restarted and refreshed folders and the icon is still not changing. The icon is an ICO I converted using an online converter in 32bit with all available sizes. The icon is named `Folder.ico` located in the same DIR as the `desktop.ini`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done through creating a `Desktop.ini` file. See here for MSDN Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/how-to-customize-folders-with-desktop-ini

**EDIT1:**

To quote from the link above:

> Use the following procedure to customize a folder's style with Desktop.ini:
>
> - Use [PathMakeSystemFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-pathmakesystemfoldera) to make the folder a system folder. This sets the read-only bit on the folder to indicate that the special behavior reserved for Desktop.ini should be enabled. You can also make a folder a system folder from the command line by using attrib +s FolderName.
> - Create a Desktop.ini file for the folder. You should mark it as hidden and system to ensure that it is hidden from normal users.
> - Make sure the Desktop.ini file that you create is in the Unicode format. This is necessary to store the localized strings that can be displayed to users.

Comment: Very cool. Can i change the font via Desktop.ini?

Comment: Does example computer have to be restarted for changes to take affect?

Comment: I can't simply make an ini file can I? I just found something about having to use commands to make it?

Comment: No, font can't be changed, only icon and some other minor information. No, the computer doesn't have to be restarted, though you may have to refresh the folder a couple of times. I have edited the post to include the step by step process, please read the linked webpage for more detailed info.

Comment: It's not working not sure why. Ill edit my question with what I've done so far and see if I'm doing something wrong perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

`IconIndex=1` must be `IconIndex=0` for .ico files.

Comment: Weird I had it to 0 and it didnt work so i changed it to 1 and it still didnt work. Now ive changed it back to 0 and it work aha

Comment: Do I have to make the folder I'm working with a system folder with command prompt for it to work or can i skip that step?

Comment: It won't let me make files hidden either.

Comment: Yes, folder needs system and read-only

Comment: If its read-only am i still able to develop my software within it? Or should I wait to customize the folders till development is done?

Comment: Really appreciate your help this is a great community. Some people are a little aggressive, but I understand why.

Comment: Read only on a folder does not make it read only